# Get email user value when update row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I've spreadsheet with my team, how can I get email user value (automatically) when they update row(based on which account they use)?

so every time they update column "task", column "email" automatically update. like the table below
[spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgDhF.png)

Comment: Existing apps script can only obtain email address from the developer. Unfortunately, you can't obtain email address from other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If users are from your same organization (so security policies allow access to the user's identity), you can just set up an Apps Script [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger that will use [getActiveUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser) or [getEffectiveUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser) to retrieve the user email.

For that, open the script editor via `Tools > Script editor` and add an `onEdit` function like the one below, which would do the following:

- Use the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to get information about the edited cell (sheet, row, column.
- Check whether the cell corresponds to the task column, is the right sheet and is not the header row.
- If it corresponds to the task column, get the user email with `getActiveUser` and use [Range.setValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValue(Object)) to write the email address to the email column.
- **Note**: In the sample below the email and task columns are set to `A` and `B` respectively, and the sheet name is set to `Sheet1`. Please change these according to your needs.

#### Code sample:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const rowIndex = range.getRow();
  const colIndex = range.getColumn();
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1"; // Sheet name you want to check
  const EMAIL_COLUMN = 1; // Column index where emails are written
  const TASK_COLUMN = 2; // Column index where tasks are written
  if (colIndex === TASK_COLUMN && rowIndex > 1 && sheet.getName() === SHEET_NAME) {
    const userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    sheet.getRange(rowIndex, EMAIL_COLUMN).setValue(userEmail);
  }
}
```

Comment: it works!! thank you..., but only show my e-mail. when I tried with another account there's nothing comes up. any idea, why??

Comment: @askstar That means security policies don't allow you access to the user's identity. Check the explanation about `getActiveUser`. What kind of accounts do you and the other users have?