# How do I extract the user that edited a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wanna add a formula or script to a Google Sheets spreadsheet that adds a column which fills in the email/user who edited another cell.

IF A1 WAS FILLED BY USER1 (appears in history), THEN B1 SHOWS "USER1"
A2 WAS FILLED BY USER5, B5 WILL SHOW "USER5".

Comment: not possible with internal formulae

Comment: Are users from your same domain? If that's the case, you can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69583310). Otherwise, this might not be possible.